# Why does Visual Studio Debugger remove \n in display?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I expected the debugger display of variable **a** in the following code to be {11\n22} it however is {1122}:

```
class A
{
    public string Text;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}

A a = new A();
a.Text = "11\n22";
```

The debugger shows in the variables window:

```
display string of the object  "{1122}"    // why not "{11\n22}" ?
a.Text                        "11\n22"
a.ToString()                  "11\n22"
```

Tested with VS2012 and VS2010. I never realized this before. Anybody knows **WHY** the display string omits the \n character?

even adding [DebuggerDisplay("Text")] gives the same result.

Comment: Windows linebreaks are `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: Thx. Changed the question name.

Comment: @Oded That doesn't really explain why the debugger shows "11\n12" in one case but "1112" in another.

Comment: @Peter - hence a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There's probably no more explanation than that it's a debugger bug.

Comment: @oded and completely unrelated to the question.  '\n' is documented as a "newline" aka linebreak.

Comment: @Michael - I agree. Took me half hour hunting where I loose my \n. In particular since even the display attribute does not print the string like, well a string, should be an argument for a bug.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me feeling sane again. I would like to treat Michael's bug comment as the answer if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to pin it and you will be see what you need.

Comment: right! interesting, hover omits \n, while after pinning the \n appears. BUG

Comment: would not consider it as the answer but a very good proof that it is a bug. so will mark this one. thx for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Visual Studio is showing the `Object.ToString()` removing all the **`whitespaces`**.

But if you copy the text & paste it onto `Notepad` it shows the string with all the `whitespaces`.

Visual studio seems to `designed/coded` that way!

Comment: it is certainly coded (do not believe designed) that way, and that is why it has a bug. can you bring up a reason why it displays {11\n22} when pinned and {1122} when hovered?

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` is **not** omitted - it is evaluated. Try inserting `\"` somewhere in the string and you will see that a double-quote appears in the helper window. Similarly, if you enter `a` into the immediate window, you will see the following:

```
a
{"11
22"}
    Text: "11\"\n\\2\"2"
```

It only appears to be omitted because the helper window you're looking at squishes everything into one line.

I imagine that this is evaluated because this is effectively a *summary* of the object, so what it's showing you is the printed value of `a.ToString()` - Visual Studio is (correctly) interpreting `\n` as a newline.